# Laravel - why are cascade-deleted tables not triggering a Model's deleted event?

Tags: laravel

I have a structure as follows:

`course
     week`

A given `week` has foreign key relation to `course` table.

In my Model for `course` and `week` I have actions to perform if there is a delete. This is done with this sort of approach in the Model:

```
public static function boot() {

        parent::boot();

        static::deleted(function($course) {
            // do some stuff;

        });
    }
```

When I delete a `course` in my backend with this line:

```
\App\Course::find($id)->delete();
```

it triggers the `deleted` event and my code goes to the above `deleted` function.

Through a cascade delete mechanism, the `week` entries for the `course` are also deleted. I confirm this in my database that `week` entries go away when a `course` is deleted.

However... the `week` Model event for `deleted` is not triggered.

Edit: I since learned that cascade deletes from database won't trigger the model events in Laravel. So I tried doing the delete of `week` items manually in the `course` model as

```
static::deleted(function($course) {

            // override any cascade deletes and do it manually
            // first delete weeks of this course:
            \App\Week::where('course_id', $course->id)->get()->each(function($week) {
                $week->delete();
            });
        });
```

That deletes the `week` items just fine but the `deleted` event for the `week` Model is still not being triggered, which I find unexpected..

Ideas?

Thanks,

Brian

Comment: *"Through a cascade delete mechanism [...]"* - Are you able to show this mechanism? I'm wondering; if your DB handles the cascade delete, that would be outside of Laravel, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the models are never actually retrieved when executing the delete statement. This is well explained in the Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#deleting-models).

> When executing a mass delete statement via Eloquent, the deleting and deleted model events will not be fired for the deleted models. This is because the models are never actually retrieved when executing the delete statement.

Answer (score 0):

The cascade happens on the DB level so you will need to manually trigger the event whenever you delete a course in order for the week observer to be notified, a bit of painful job, but this can do it I think:

```
// I don't know your relationship, but this is the template that you should use
// Change App\Week with your model with full namespace, and pass the Week instance 
// as a parameter
event('eloquent.deleted: App\Week', $course->week);
```

Based on your edit, you will need to do this in order to work:

```
\App\Week::where('course_id', $course->id)->get()->each(function($week) {
    $week->delete();
});
```

I cannot test this but I am sure it should work, as the events fire on an Eloquent instance not on QueryBuilder as you do.

Comment: Hi, can you see any reason why the deleted event still wouldn't be getting called if I do what I show in my edited post? That is, I am now deleting week items manually.

Comment: In course controller I delete as such: \App\Course::find($id)->delete() That then takes me to Course deleted event in model. Now, in debugger, when I evaluate \App\Course::find($id) it is a Model type, not eloquent. But the model deleted event is still firing. That is why I can't figure out why the Week deleted event isn't firing, since I am using similar approach.

Comment: Interestingly enough, that is what I am currently doing based on what I saw here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2536, but still not triggering. Maybe has something to do with how I am using API controller for the Course delete and maybe that somehow makes my Week deletes not set in motion the events I would expect.

Comment: Ok, I think I know why...  After Course is deleted, the database is deleting Week items based on the cascade delete, so I probably need to turn off cascade delete. But I don't want to do that since at times I do deletes directly in phpmyadmin. So I guess I need to look into observers as you said - question being, will observers still work if the Week delete is happening in database via cascade delete?

Comment: If the event is fired in the course and you fire an event, the observer will be fired for sure. If you directly remove from the database or using the QueryBuilder then no it won't.

Comment: I don't see how I am using query builder if at top of my Model I have `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;`

Comment: You have that because the class extends the Model.. Try `dd(\App\Week::where('course_id', $course->id));` and you'll see what it returns. You should read the documentation my friend.