# Deleted method is not called on one of Laravel's models

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6, voyager

I am using Laravel 6 with Voyager admin panel.

I have two different Laravel models and I am deleting their items from Voyager admin panel, deletion works well for items of both models.

I want to add some actions on model deleting so I add this code to both models.
It works for model A but not working for model B, I don't know why and how can I debug and fix it.

```
    public static function boot() {
      parent::boot();
    
      static::deleted(function($model) {
        someaction();
      });
    }
```

The only two differences between models I found

1. Model B has cascading deletion in its DB migration
2. Model B extends \TCG\Voyager\Models\User

Comment: Please add a [mre] to your question including information on the relevant models, the database structure, and most importantly *what action* you are taking that you think should trigger this event.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a event bind class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use App\Item;
use Log;

class ItemEvent
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function itemDeleted(Item $item)
    {
        Log::info("Item Deleted Event Fire: ".$item);
    }
}
```

register on event provider:

```
class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */

    protected $listen = [

        'App\Events\Event' => [
            'App\Listeners\EventListener',
        ],
        'item.deleted' => [
            'App\Events\ItemEvent@itemDeleted',
        ]
    ];

    /**
     * Register any events for your application.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
    }
}
```

and you could test it firing on booting model like so:

```
class Item extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'price'];

    public static function boot() {

        parent::boot();

        static::deleted(function($item) {
            \Log::info('Item Deleted Event:'.$item);
        });
        static::deleting(function($item) {
            \Log::info('Item Deleting Event:'.$item);
        });
        
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain whys this should work and what is the difference between models that I have?

Comment: The difference is that you have to create an event to handle model firing events and register them, so is no need to handle it on boot method, I put here to just Log and have assurance the event item deleting was firing

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned Model B has cascade delete on migration. This is most likely the cause. The delete event won't be fired because the delete happens on database level and not through Laravel. If you still need the events for this, you could handle the delete through the app instead of cascade delete. Another approach would be to watch the delete event on foreign key model, and then handle your function. [Here's a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58030845/laravel-why-are-cascade-deleted-tables-not-triggering-a-models-deleted-event) that might help.
To further confirm if cascade delete is the cause, try manually deleting something from your Model B through the app (`ModelB::find(1)->delete()`).

Apart from that, if you're [deleting records through query](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#deleting-models-using-queries) (`ModelB::where('something', 1)->delete()`), it won't be fired either.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using laravel's observers in order to trigger certain code on events including creation, update, deletion...

you can see the reference here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers

after creating the observer you add this code to your model:

```
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        MyModel::observe(MyModelObserver::class);
    }
```